# How to change a manually entered url in browser to another url in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want that url i am entering in browser should automatically change into other url.
For example
If i entered http//www.google.com/
 it should automatically divert me to http//www.google.com/#/home/messages

Comment: Do you want to change the URL for only the sites you have developed, or do you literally want to redirect from google?

Comment: I want it for my application that i am developing,

Answer (score 0):

if you use ui-router, you can refer this gist:
https://gist.github.com/nikoloza/4ab3a94a3c6511bb1dac

Comment: Thanks , but i think it will take a event to trigger , for example some state or clicking on button , will it work on manually entering a url?